# Filter rows in a data indexed object in R

Tags: r

I am new to R. I have a data indexed onject which I need to filter so that I can get every Xth data point. How do I go about doing this?
Code used to create the data was:

```
temp <- blpGetData(conn, securities[1], fields=values,start=startdate,end=enddate, barsize=interval, barfields=tick,retval=datatype)
assign(paste(gsub(" +","",repl[1])),temp)
name <- paste("merge(",paste(gsub(" +","",repl[1])))
suf <- paste(", suffixes=c('.",paste(gsub(" +","",repl[1])),"'",sep="")

for(i in 2:length(securities)){
    temp <- blpGetData(conn, securities[i], 
                       fields=values,
                       start=startdate,
                       end=enddate, 
                       barsize=interval, 
                       barfields=tick,
                       retval=datatype)
    assign(paste(gsub(" +","",repl[i])),temp)
    name <- paste(name,",",paste(gsub(" +","",repl[i])))
    suf <- paste(suf,",'.",paste(gsub(" +","",repl[i])),"'",sep="")
} 
name <- paste(name,suf,"))")
mat <- eval(parse(text=name))
```

I want every Xth row. `mat` is the object.

```
 > cat(name) 
 PX_OPEN..CINC1 PX_HIGH..CINC1 PX_LOW..CINC1 PX_LAST..CINC1 PX_OPEN..CINC5 PX_HIGH..CINC5 PX_LOW..CINC5 PX_LAST..CINC5 PX_OPEN..UST10Y PX_HIGH..UST10Y PX_LOW..UST10Y PX_LAST..UST10Y

 > str(mat) ‘zoo’ series from 2011-11-11 to 2012-01-18
 Data: num [1:49, 1:12] 206 205 205 212 219 ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 ..$ : NULL
 ..$ : chr [1:12] "PX_OPEN..CINC1" "PX_HIGH..CINC1" "PX_LOW..CINC1" "PX_LAST..CINC1" 
 ... Index: Date[1:49], format: "2011-11-11" "2011-11-14" "2011-11-15" "2011-11-16" "2011-11-17" "2011-11-18" ...
```

Comment: Can you do `cat(name)` and `str(mat)` please? - just helps to work out what's going on. cheers!

Comment: cat(name)
PX_OPEN..CINC1 PX_HIGH..CINC1 PX_LOW..CINC1 PX_LAST..CINC1 PX_OPEN..CINC5 PX_HIGH..CINC5 PX_LOW..CINC5 PX_LAST..CINC5 PX_OPEN..UST10Y PX_HIGH..UST10Y PX_LOW..UST10Y PX_LAST..UST10Y> 
> str(mat)
‘zoo’ series from 2011-11-11 to 2012-01-18
  Data: num [1:49, 1:12] 206 205 205 212 219 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:12] "PX_OPEN..CINC1" "PX_HIGH..CINC1" "PX_LOW..CINC1" "PX_LAST..CINC1" ...
  Index:  Date[1:49], format: "2011-11-11" "2011-11-14" "2011-11-15" "2011-11-16" "2011-11-17" "2011-11-18" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you told us what your object is. A vector? A list?

If it's a vector called `myvector` and you want every `x`th data point starting from the first you can use `seq(...)` to generate the sequence `1, 1+x, 1+2*x, 1+3*x, ...` to index into your object. See `?seq`.

e.g.:

```
myvector <- runif(100) # generate vector of 100 random values
idx      <- seq(1,length(myvector),by=10) # get every 10th value starting from
                                          # & including 1,
myvector[idx] # every 10th value: elements 1, 11, 21, ...
```

**UPDATE**

Since your object is two-dimensional, try:

```
n   <- 5 # get every 5th object
idx <- seq(1,nrow(mat),by=n)
mat[idx,]
```

Comment: Error in `[.zoo`(data, idx) : subscript out of bounds  It is indexed by date and is more like a matrix. > dim(data) gives [1] 49 12

Comment: Again you have to tell me what your object is before I can help you. Please edit your question showing how you create your object or what package it is from. Also, what do you mean by "Every Xth data point" if it's a matrix? "Every Xth row"? "Every Xth column"?

Comment: edited the questoin witht hte code. The class of the object is zoo if that is relevant. Again, apologies as I am new and have to edit someone else's code.